# Django - Image doesn't load when using pdf view

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-easy-pdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-pdf) and I have the following view:

```
class PrescriptionView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = 'meds/prescription.html'
    context_object_name = 'meds'
    model = Medicament

    def get_queryset(self):
        ids = map(int, self.kwargs['selected'].split(","))
        return Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PrescriptionView, self).get_context_data(pagesize="A5", title="Ordonnance", **kwargs)
        return context
```

And I have the following html page:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            @page { size: A5;
                @frame headerLogo {
                    top: 23mm;
                    left: 20mm;
                    width: 50mm;
                    height: 24mm;
                    -pdf-frame-content: headerLogo;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="headerLogo">
        <img src="{% static 'img/banner.png' %}">
    </div>
</body>
```

But the banner.png image doesn't load and I keep getting the following error:

```
missing explicit frame definition for content or just static frames

getFile '/static/img/banner.png' None '/home/nids/cabin'
'<div id="headerLogo"> <img src="/static/img/banner.png"/> </div>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/context.py", line 828, in _getFileDeprecated
    nv = self.pathCallback(name, relative)
  File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy_pdf/rendering.py", line 35, in fetch_resources
    path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ""))
  File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'
Need a valid file name!
'<img src="/static/img/banner.png"/>'
line 0, msg: missing explicit frame definition for content or just static frames, fragment: 
line 0, msg: getFile %r %r %r, fragment: '<div id="headerLogo"> <img src="/static/img/banner.png"/> </div>'
line 0, msg: Need a valid file name!, fragment: '<img src="/static/img/banner.png"/>'
```

I don't have problems with my static files in other views except this pdf one!

Answer (score -2):

Almost 10 hours had tried to solve that problem, AND OH MA GOD, IT'S SOLVED.
Problem was very simple - **reinstall** this packages

1.pip install --pre xhtml2pdf.

2.pip install --pre reportlab.

3.pip install django-easy-pdf.

Just remember to **uninstall before** this commands.
And one more thing, try to set height and width to img tag on pure html.